# Is there a difference between glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0) and glClear(COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)?

Tags: opengl

Both clear the color buffer, right? Do they do it the same way?

Comment: BTW- no such thing as "color matrix" if we want to be strict, "color buffer" would be more precise in OGL terms. (Just mentioning)

Comment: @Kos: Just an interesting tidbit: there is something called a color matrix in OpenGL (in a SGI extension). It's used for things like hue rotation. [docs](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/SGI/color_matrix.txt)

Comment: @Stefan, thanks! I haven't heard of that. But today we anyway have pixel shaders for that, don't we :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`glClear`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glClear) actually clears the buffer, while [`glClearColor`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glClearColor) just sets the colour to clear the buffer to.

Answer (score 3):

glClear is a **Command**: which clears the buffer.

glClearColor is **State Setting**: which sets the color value to buffer.

Comment: why answer with the same answer as the accepted answer, 4 years in delay, without adding any value? I wonder...